# Trying to migrate the closed WI and getting the 503 error, can you please check

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

## [                 Bug][Complete: 55/837][sid:16308 |Rev:15 ][tid:null   | Found 15 revisions to migrate on  Work item:16308

[                 Bug][Complete: 55/837][sid:16308 |Rev:15 ][tid:null   | ...FAILED to Save
[                 Bug][Complete: 55/837][sid:16308 |Rev:15 ][tid:null   | Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException: HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.IsAuthenticationChallenge(TfsMessage requestMessage, HttpWebResponse webResponse, WebException webException, TfsMessage& responseMessage)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.ClientService.GetWorkItem(Int32 workItemId, Int32 revisionId, Int32 minimumRevisionId, Nullable`1 asOfDate, Boolean useMaster, RowSetCollection& workItem, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, RowSetCollection& metadata) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.GetWorkItem(String requestId, Int32 workItemId, Int32 revisionId, Int32 minimumRevisionId, Nullable`1 asOfDate, Boolean useMaster, IWorkItemRowSets& workItem, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.LoadWorkItem(Int32 id, Int32 rev, Nullable`1 asof, IWorkItemRowSets& witem) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem..ctor(WorkItemStore store, Int32 id, Int32 revision) at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemStoreContext.GetRevision(WorkItem workItem, Int32 revision) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\ComponentContext\WorkItemStoreContext.cs:line 202 at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ReplayRevisions(List`1 revisionsToMigrate, WorkItem sourceWorkItem, WorkItem targetWorkItem, Project destProject, WorkItemStoreContext sourceStore, Int32 current, WorkItemStoreContext targetStore) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 323
[                 Bug][Complete: 55/837][sid:16308 |Rev:15 ][tid:null   | System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ProcessWorkItem(WorkItemStoreContext sourceStore, WorkItemStoreContext targetStore, Project destProject, WorkItem sourceWorkItem, Int32 retryLimit, Int32 retrys) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 197
migration.exe Warning: 0 :   [EXCEPTION] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ProcessWorkItem(WorkItemStoreContext sourceStore, WorkItemStoreContext targetStore, Project destProject, WorkItem sourceWorkItem, Int32 retryLimit, Int32 retrys) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 244
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 124
at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.MigrationContextBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\MigrationContextBase.cs:line 35

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the [setup instructions](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/server-configuration.html)?

The account that you are running the migration under needs to be a Collection Admin on the target server and for a local instance you need to enable the bypass rules for that accont below.

**Bypass Rules**
For on-premises TFS instances you need to be part of the Project Collection Service Accounts group. You can do this by calling the following command:

```
tfssecurity /g+ "Project Collection Service Accounts" n:domainusername ALLOW /server:http://myserver:8080/tfs
```

This is not required for cloud targets.

Comment: my account is project admin, i created the project in target both are cloud (source and target)